# ERL: execute erl command from shell

Tags: bash, erlang, ejabberd, erl

so here is what I want - to execute the following mini script from bash shell:

```
mnesia:change_table_copy_type(schema, node(), disc_copies).
```

I am trying to find out the possibilities but can not find a clear answer. There is a "-noshell" option, or, "-oldshell" option but none of them say how to execute any command like the one above.

How do I do that?

Comment: Try `erl -noshell -eval 'mnesia:change_table_copy_type(schema, node(), disc_copies)' -run init stop`.

Comment: Thanks Dogbert, that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-noshell` with `-eval "mnesia:change_table_copy_type(schema, node(), disc_copies)"` for this. You'll also have to pass `-run init stop` after that to make sure the Erlang VM stops after running the command, or the VM will keep running even after evaluating the `-eval` code.

```
erl -noshell -eval "mnesia:change_table_copy_type(schema, node(), disc_copies)" -run init stop
```